# Error in SQL syntax statement when updating database

Tags: sql, syntax

C# keeps coming up with an error:

Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax

My SQL statement is at the bottom in the picture.

[image]

Sql statement:

```
Update amazon_ordred_items
Set OrderItemId = 666854391288218,
    SellerSKu = ..,
    Title = 2pcs Fashion Cool Universal Black Real Original Car Headlight Eyelashes Sticker,
    QuantityOrdered = 1,
    QuantityShipped = 1,
    CurrencyCode = USD,
    Amount = 0.50,
    ScheduledDeliveryEndDate = ..,
    ScheduledDeliveryStartDate = ..,
    PromotionIds = .,
Where ASIN = B00EISTU74
```

Comment: Can you make an effort to post the SQL at least...

Comment: the last few lines are the statement that was submitted

Comment: Please post the full SQL statement as formatted **text**, not a screenshot. And include the *complete* error message. And update the tags to state which DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

One thing which would make this a lot better is to add quotes around the text strings in the query:

```
update table
set  sellerSK='.',
     Title='2pcs Fashion...',
     (etc)
```

Can't tell from the screenshot if this is the problem, but it certainly looks like it is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not using single quotes for any of your string values in the `update` statement. Put quotes on every value that is not an integer and the sql statement will work.

Also you have values of `..` for some date fields. Assuming those are of an SQL data type `DateTime` or similar, this will not work. If you don't have a date, use `Null` instead.

```
Update amazon_ordred_items
Set OrderItemId = 666854391288218,
    SellerSKu = Null,
    Title = '2pcs Fashion Cool Universal Black Real Original Car Headlight Eyelashes Sticker',
    QuantityOrdered = 1,
    QuantityShipped = 1,
    CurrencyCode = 'USD',
    Amount = 0.50,
    ScheduledDeliveryEndDate = Null,
    ScheduledDeliveryStartDate = Null,
    PromotionIds = Null,
Where ASIN = 'B00EISTU74'
```

Note also there's no need to update the ASIN field since you're not changing it's value and it is in your `Where` clause.